# .count vs .count() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been going through some built in functions in python as a refresher course and wanted to get some input on this snip of code that counts the majority number of occurrences in a list.

```py
def function(Array):
   return max(set(Array), key = Array.count) 

# wondering what .count vs .count() does in this situation
```

Comment: `()` calls a function.  So `Array.count` is a function, `Array.count()` is what you get from calling the function `Array.count`.  When you pass a `key` to `max`, you're passing it a function (in this case `Array.count`) that `max` itself will call as it's figuring out what the biggest item is, not the result of you calling the function yourself.

Comment: Due to the set function,  there will always only be one occurrence.  For majority occurrence in list: `return max(Array, key = Array.count)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.count will set key to the function that this refers to while Array.count() will run the function and set key to the return of the function